# Where condition on list of jsonb in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb

Let's say I have the table `food_articles`, which has the following columns: `name`(type ="text") and `ingredients`(type="jsonb[]"), where the ingredient jsonb object looks like this:

```
{
    ingredient_id: 'string',
    quantity: 'number'
}
```

How would I create a query that returns all rows in `food_articles` that has the `ingredient_id = 1337` in the ingredients jsonb array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `where` clause unnest `ingredients` into a table and check whether a record exists with `ingredient_id = '1337'`.

```sql
select * from food_articles 
where exists
(
 select 
 from unnest(ingredients) arj 
 where arj ->> 'ingredient_id' = '1337' 
);
```

Please note that if the type of `ingredients` is jsonb that contains an array like this one `'[{"ingredient_id":"1337","quantity":1},{"ingredient_id":"1336","quantity":2}]'` rather than a Postgres array of jsonb elements (i.e. jsonb[]) then you can use the 'contains' `@>` operator simply as

```sql
where ingredients @> '[{"ingredient_id":"1337"}]'
```

Comment: The first code snippet you suggested works!
However using the `@>` operator does not work, it says: "DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions."
Even though the column is of type jsonb[]

Comment: Yes, it expects `jsonb`, not `jsonb[]` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table "food_articles" ("name" text, "ingredients" jsonb);

insert into "food_articles" values('food 1', jsonb_build_object('ingredient_id', 1, 'quantity', 1)),
 ('food 2', jsonb_build_object('ingredient_id',2, 'quantity',1337)),
('food 3', jsonb_build_object('ingredient_id',3, 'quantity',1337)),
('food 3', jsonb_build_object('ingredient_id', 3, 'quantity',1332));

select * from "food_articles"
where "ingredients"->>'quantity'='1337';
```

Playground link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b6ab520a44c65656ebc767a10f5737b6

Documentation for postgresql jsonb manipulation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html